# test is exiting before the method which has async.waterfall, is executed

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, jestjs, async.js

I'm currently writing unit tests for an API. One of the helper functions is the `async.waterfall` to avoid "callback hell". I made this method async and await where the method is called.

The test is exiting saying `Number of calls: 0` in Node.js. I'm using Jest as my test framework.

Method being tested:

```
outletInfoController.fetchAllOutletsByUserIdAndCityId = async function (req, res) {
        var userId = req.body.userId;
        var cityId = req.body.cityId;
         await outletInfoHelper.fetchAllOutletsByUserIdAndCityId(userId, cityId, function (error, result) {
            if (error || !result) {
                responseUtils.buildAndRespond(commonConst.CODE.FAILURE_RESPONSE_CODE, commonConst.MESSAGE.FAILURE_RESPONSE_MESSAGE,
                    error, null, res);
            } else {
                responseUtils.buildAndRespond(commonConst.CODE.SUCCESS_RESPONSE_CODE, commonConst.MESSAGE.SUCCESS_RESPONSE_MESSAGE,
                    null, result, res);
            }
        });
    };
```

Method which is using `async.waterfall`:

```
outletInfoHelper.fetchAllOutletsByUserIdAndCityId = async function (userId, cityId, outerCallback) {
        async.waterfall(
            [function getRestaurantsByUserId(callback) {
                //do something
            }, function getRestaurantsDetails(restIds, callback) {
                //do something
            }, function getRestaurantsUserCount(restaurants, callback) {
                //do something
            }], function (error, results) {
                //do something
            });
     }
```

Test code snippet:

```
test("outletInfo_success_response", async () => {
        let req = {
            body: {
                userId: 8881,
                cityId: 211
            }
        };

        let restIds = [];
        await factory.restaurantListFactory((result) => {
            restIds = result;
        });

        await fetchUserRestaurantObjFromUserId.mockImplementation((userId, cb) => {
            cb(null, restIds);
        });

        let mockResponse = [];
        await factory.restaurantObjectsFactory(function (result) {
            mockResponse = result;
        });

        let successResp = {
            statusMessage: 'success',
            data: mockResponse,
            errorMessage: null,
            statusCode: 0
        }

        await fetchRestaurantsFromIdsAndCityId.mockImplementation((restIds, cityId, cb) => {
            cb(null, mockResponse);
        });
        
        let response;
        await factory.getUserRestMap((result) => {
            response = result;
        });

        await fetchUsersFromOutletId.mockImplementation((restIds, cb) => {
            cb(null, response);
        });
        
        let res = await getResponseObj();

        await outletInfoController.fetchAllOutletsByUserIdAndCityId(req, res);
        expect(res.send).toBeCalledWith(successResp);
    });
```

Comment: You should never pass a callback *and* expect the function to return an `await`able promise